# What is the Samsung link preview user agent?

Tags: metadata, bots, user-agent, meta

Starting in the Samsung GS8, the messages app will generate a link preview from the meta data on a site.  Need help finding the user agent string for the crawler that preview feature is using to grab the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out the user agent string used by their bot is just an old version of Firefox for linux.  Here it is:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0
```

Comment: your answer was usefull, because its still the same, so we can somehow trust in it to identify this bot!